# How to populate a web page form using VB6

Tags: html, vb6

What I would like to do is populating a login form web page using VB6.
I use the following code:

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer   
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument  
Dim COL As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim ELEMENT As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://app.listonic.com/lists"

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
Set COL = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each ELEMENT In COL
    If ELEMENT.innerHTML = "Sign In" Then ELEMENT.Click
Next ELEMENT

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set COL = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each ELEMENT In COL
    Debug.Print "Inner HTML - " & ELEMENT.innerHTML
    Debug.Print "Outer HTML - " & ELEMENT.outerHTML
    Debug.Print ELEMENT.getAttribute("name")

    If ELEMENT.getAttribute("name") = "Email" Then
        Call ELEMENT.setAttribute("Value", "yourid@server.com")
    End If
    'If ELEMENT.innerHTML = "Sign In" Then ELEMENT.Click
Next ELEMENT
```

The problem is that this code:

```
Call ELEMENT.setAttribute("Value", "yourid@server.com")
```

does not work. I mean by this, I cannot see "yourid@server.com" address on the web page in Email field.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found something. instead of this:

```
Call ELEMENT.setAttribute("Value", "yourid@server.com")
```

I put this:

```
ELEMENT.Value = "yourid@server.com"
```

This put the email address into "Email" field, but **I cannot click the "Sign In" button** since it is **disabled** on the page. It turns enabled when I type manually something in "Email" and "Password" fields (of course I have populated password field as well).

Any hints on how to enable "Sign In" from vb6 code?